# When using Keen, querying with absolute timeframe with monthly intervals using JavaScript is not splitting as expected

Tags: javascript, keen-io

I'm using **keen-analysis.js** and **keen-dataviz.js** framework.

When trying to query and chart data by month, if my datetime has timezone offset information the results are not divided as expected.

This is the javascript I'm using:

```
var query1 = new Keen.Query('count', {
  event_collection: "accounts",
  interval: "monthly",
  timeframe: {
    end: (new Date(2017, 3, 1)).toISOString(),    // "2017-04-01T05:00:00.000Z"
    start: (new Date(2017, 0, 1)).toISOString(),  // "2017-01-01T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  timezone: "US/Eastern"
});

var query2 = new Keen.Query('count', {
  event_collection: "accounts",
  interval: "monthly",
  timeframe: {
    end: '2017-04-01T00:00:00.000',
    start: '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000'
  },
  timezone: "US/Eastern"
});

window.onload=function(){
  var chart1 = new Dataviz()
    .el("#chart1")
    .title("query1 results")
    .height(100)
    .type("area")
    .prepare();

  client
    .run(query1)
    .then(function(res){
      chart1 
        .data(res)
        .render();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      chart1
        .message(err.message);
    });

  var chart2 = new Dataviz()
    .el("#chart2")
    .title("query2 results")
    .height(100)
    .type("area")
    .prepare();

  client
    .run(query2)
    .then(function(res){
      chart2 
        .data(res)
        .render();
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      chart2
        .message(err.message);
    });
}
```

And here is a screen shot of the result. Notice that in query1, January is mentioned twice.

[image: Rendered charts]

I believe that it has to do with the response, in which the timezone offset in query1 is lost in the first interval in the "end" property. This initial loss of data I'm guessing has a cascading effect.

[image: Logs of responses]

I would like to know is this a bug or expected result. If it's expected, what change should I make to my code. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a full answer but the `timezone` parameter in your query shouldn't have any effect since it is only relevant for queries that use relative timeframes like `previous_2_days`. For queries with a start and end time, the time will be whatever is specified in the ISOtimestamp that you provide (in this case, with the T05:00:00.000Z, you are saying that the start and end bounds of the query are 5am UTC).

Comment: Your result makes me wonder if including the `timezone` is effecting the way the interval parameter is used, effectively skewing the start and end time of the "monthly" buckets to be in US/Eastern. Do you have the same results when you remove the timezone parameter?

Comment: A final note is that the presentation of the data is separate from the querying of the data, so it's very good to inspect both the query response and the resulting chart (as you are!). The charting library (C3.js) uses your browser's timezone to determine the labels of the chart. If your browser's timezone doesn't match the buckets for the datapoints, the presentation can be strange. For example a timestamp that is on the edge of Dec/Jan might be labeled as December in one browser, but January in another. That might be related to what is happening here.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the Z from your query 1 timeframes and it will behave like query 2. It is recommended that you *should* use `timezone` on queries as it has the added benefit of accounting for daylight savings time. It's when you include timezone both as a query parameter and as a timestamp offset that things get confusing. Generally, the timezone parameter is overridden to use whatever timezone offset is specified in your timestamps (in this case Z/UTC).

The presentation of multiple months in your first chart is related to how the months are chopped up. You have a partial month starting at 5am on Jan 1 in UTC which presents as "January" in your browser, then you have a full month starting on Feb 1 in UTC which also presents as January because it is still January in your local time. Then your month starting in March is presenting as February since it is Feb in local time.